# JQuery.Ajax and MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a need to call a method on my controller to return a complex type using the JQuery.Ajax method.

```
 function CallMethodTest(Id) {
            //alert(Id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //data: "{'Id': '" + Id + "'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string MyMethod()
{
    return "ABC"; // Gives me the error on the first alert of "200" and the second alert "Syntax Error: Invalid Character"
    return "1"; // Works fine
}
```

As the code explains, if I return an integer (as a string) the return works and I alert "1", however, If I try and return any alpha characters I get the alerts shown in the comments of MyMethod.

Comment: Your ajax method is expecting json, this is probably the cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you add `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` to your `WebMethod`

Comment: I've added [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] to my webmethod, but with no luck. I'm actually wanting to return a complex type eventually so JSON will be needed for that I assume, the returning of a string was only to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Just a note, your `url` is `/MyController/MyMethod` so why are you adding the `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` code? For me I would just have `public ActionResult MyMethod()` and from in that I would return `return Json("ABC");`

Comment: I've just seen another post where they have done that and tested it. Works brilliantly. Add that as an answer Tim and I'll accept. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your code, it looks as though you are returning the value from your Controller `url: "/MyController/MyMethod"`

If you are returning the value from your controller, then get rid of the `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` code and replace it with this `ActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(){
    return Json("ABC");
}
```

Also, if you are ever going to call a method in your controller via `GET` then use

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(){
    return Json("ABC", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In View You use the following code,

```
  function ItemCapacity() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ItemCapacityList", "SalesDept")',
            data: { 'itemCategoryId': itemCategoryIds },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var capacityCounter = 0;
                var capacitySelected = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {

                    var tr = $("#gvSpareSetItemsDetails tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")");
                    var categoryId = $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text();
                    var isSelectOrNot = $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').find('select');

                    if (isSelectOrNot.is('select')) {

                        $.map(data, function (item) {
                            if (categoryId == item.ItemCategoryID) {
                                isSelectOrNot.get(0).options[isSelectOrNot.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.CapacityDescription, item.ItemCapacityID);
                                capacityCounter = capacityCounter + 1;
                                capacitySelected = item.ItemCapacityID;
                            }
                        });

                        if (capacityCounter == 1) {
                            isSelectOrNot.val(capacitySelected);
                        }

                        capacityCounter = 0;
                        capacitySelected = "";
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function () { alert("Connection Failed. Please Try Again"); }
        });
    }
}
```

In the Controller Use the following Code,

```
    public JsonResult ItemCapacityList(string itemCategoryId)
    {
        List<ItemCapacity> lsItemCapacity = new List<ItemCapacity>();

        string[] itemCategory = itemCategoryId.Split('#');

        int itemCategoryLength = itemCategory.Length, rowCount = 0;
        string itemCategoryIds = string.Empty;

        for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < itemCategoryLength; rowCount++)
        {
            itemCategoryIds += "'" + itemCategory[rowCount].Trim() + "',";
        }

        itemCategoryIds = itemCategoryIds.Remove(itemCategoryIds.Length - 1);

        lsItemCapacity = salesDal.ReadItemCapacityByCategoryId(itemCategoryIds);

        return new JsonResult { Data = lsItemCapacity };
    }
```